# linux system call implementation

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

Where can I find the source code of some of the system calls? For example, I am looking for the implementation of `fstat` as described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html).

Comment: They're defined in the kernel source using SYSCALL_DEFINEx, for example [fstat here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/stat.c#L203).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is mostly implemented inside the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), with a tiny glue code in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). But see also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).

From the user-land point of view, a system call (they are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) is a single machine instruction (often `SYSENTER`) with some [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (e.g. defining which machine register hold the syscall number - e.g. `__NR_stat` from `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`....-, and which other registers contain the arguments to the system call).

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/strace.1.html) to understand which system calls are done by a given program or process.

The C standard library has a tiny wrapper function (which invokes the kernel, following the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), and deals with error reporting & `errno`).

For [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), the C wrapping function is e.g. in [stat/stat.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stat/stat.c) for [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/).

Inside the [kernel](http://kernel.org/) code, most of the work happens in [fs/stat.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/stat.c?id=refs/tags/v4.4.1) (e.g. after line 207).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690642/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535056/how-does-linux-kernel-prevents-the-bios-system-calls/19535900#19535900) answers